# Angular5 & Laravel fonts, images, js missing

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5, angular5, laravel-5.5

I compile my project using this https://github.com/ilirhushi/laravel5.5-angular5

When I build the project all fonts, images, and some part of js missing.

it builds in public/dist folder, so I have problems with url , I mean that of I will change destination of images (move them to high level) it will work, but it's a bad way

So can anyway give me an advice how I can change buiding path for images, fonts, js?